# C compiler ??) replacement

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, compiler-construction, string-literals

We faced a strange issue with the Visual Studio 2005 compiler.
At compile time, it replaces this string constant

```
"... ,0x??)"
```

with this one:

```
"... ,0x]"
```

We hardly learned by trying that the following replacements are performed:

```
??(   ->   [
??)   ->   ]
??<   ->   {
??>   ->   }
```

So I guess this should be a feature, not a bug.
The Visual Studio 2010 doesn't do that.

Too bad you can't search with Google for `??(`.
So the question is:

**Can we control this behavior by a compiler switch?**

BTW: What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are C digraphs and trigraphs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs

And yes, you can disable them in visual studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462497.aspx

Comment: Digraphs wouldn't have this problem, as digraphs are alternate spellings of tokens, rather than alternate spellings of characters. `"<:"` consists of two characters (three if you count the trailing `'\0'`)

Comment: I'm impressed. It seems that the `/Zc` compiler switch only exists to VS 2010 and above. So for VS 2005 we have a problem. But I figured out that simply escaping the `?` does the job: `\?\?)`